# Как Entity Framework понимает правильность названия класса?

Tags: entity-framework

У меня в БД есть таблица "Cities".
В моём проекте я создаю класс "City".

Я считываю и вывожу на экран список городов из этой таблицы.
Если я назову свой класс, предположим, "Cit", то EF создаст таблицы "Cit" в БД и она будет пустая.

Как EF понимает единственное и множ числа в названиях классов и таблиц БД ?

Answer (score 6):

Для этой цели используется [PluarisationService](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Data.Entity.Design/System/Data/Entity/Design/PluralizationService/PluralizationService.cs) - класс для преобразования имен собственных в множественные.

Его фабричный метод возвращает экземпляр конкретной реализации этого класса для необходимого языка. Однако пока реализованы только правила преобразования для английского.

Даже для английского языка правила преобразований довольно сложны и запутаны. Можете [покопаться в коде текущей реализации](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Data.Entity.Design/System/Data/Entity/Design/PluralizationService/EnglishPluralizationService.cs). 
Там проверяются префиксы, суффиксы, исключения, нестандартные собственные, и ещё много другого. Очень интересно и познавательно.

Код этот написан в соответствии с действующими правилами грамматики английского языка, по которым ваше слово "Cit" не является корректным собственным именем. По факту - это сокращение, которое естевственно нельзя пребразовать в множественное число

Comment: Благодарю! Очень познавательно!

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что он никак не понимает правильность названия.
Просто берет то название, которое есть, и переводит его во множественное число, если заранее не отключить такое поведение (`PluralizingTableNameConvention`). Если отключить, то использует имя класса.
Кроме того возможно через аннотации или api задать таблицам произвольные имена.

```
[Table("Cities")]
class Cit {
...
}
```

Comment: Благодарю! Я про такое поведение не знал.